# What does "<!-- ... //-->" in Javascript mean?

Tags: javascript

Some older(?) Javascript sometimes includes `<!-- ... //-->` like

```
<script>
    <!--
    var text1="bla";
    var text2="bla";
    //-->
</script>
```

What does that do? Comment out? Why?

And do you still use that today?

Comment: Its like a comment section for html.

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780047/html-comments-in-a-javascript-block)

Comment: [HTML Comments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#html_comments) on MDN Web Docs.

Comment: Duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130324/what-does-in-html-mean/30131015

Comment: @AmitMondal While the question you linked to is definitely related, this question is not a duplicate of that one because this question specifically addresses the (outdated) use of HTML-style syntax for comments **in a JavaScript context**. (This question is now marked as a duplicate of another question, which does deal specifically with this same issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to comment out lines in html similar to "text"/'''text''' in python or // in a few other languages.
Commenting a line will not process/execute it.